# How to create a file in titanium?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

How to create a file in titanium? can anyone give me a piece of code for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Working+with+Local+Data#WorkingwithLocalData-FilesystemStorage

There is a lot of helpful information in the wiki links I have provided you and in the appcelerator documentation.

I would suggest looking there before posting a question, it might save you some time

https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink

Answer (score -1):

var filename = 'test.txt';
var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,filename);

This should create the file automatically in your Resources folder.